# How to extend the result of the query into separate column in SQL?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT 
    COUNT (*)
FROM 
    table
WHERE 
    column2 > 10

UNION 

SELECT 
    COUNT (*)
FROM 
    table
WHERE 
    column3 > 10

UNION 

SELECT 
    COUNT (*)
FROM 
    table
WHERE 
    column3 > 10

UNION
```

Results:

```
(No column name)
155
433
931
```

How to put the results into a new column?

```
Column1   Column2    Column3
155         433          931
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
(
  SELECT 
    COUNT (*)
    FROM table
    WHERE column2 > 10
) AS [col1],
(
  SELECT 
    COUNT (*)
    FROM table
  WHERE column3 > 10
) AS [col2],
(
  SELECT 
    COUNT (*)
    FROM table
  WHERE column3 > 10
) AS [col3]
```

Should do the trick

Comment: Yep, it did!! Thanks a lot!